# How to search a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, search, actionbarsherlock, adapter

So I have a custom listview with it's own adapter class, and the listview has 2 textview's and one imageview. I want users to be able to click on the search button in the action bar and search for either of the textviews in my custom list. The problem is, I have no idea how to do this. If anyone could help me, it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Also a side note: I'm using ActionBarSherlock

Here is the adapter for my listview:

```
public class ItemIDAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private String[] mStrings;
    private String[] mIds;
    private TypedArray mIcons;

    private int mViewResourceId;

    public ItemIDAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
            String[] strings, String[] ids, TypedArray icons) {
        super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mStrings = strings;
        mIds = ids;
        mIcons = icons;

        mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mStrings[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
        iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemids);
        tv1.setText(mIds[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And this is the class where I display the listview:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context ctx = getApplication();
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();

        String[] options = res.getStringArray(R.array.item_ids);
        String[] ids = res.getStringArray(R.array.item_names);
        TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.item_images);

        setListAdapter(new ItemIDAdapter(ctx, R.layout.idslistitem, ids, options, icons));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the text that user wrote in your mString variable.

And this link can help you : http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/forum/thread/550920/Tutorial-How-to-Add-search-function-to-custom-Listview

Comment: Unfortuneately this doesn't help me. I can't get the example to work with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditText to search then you have to write your own filter method..here is an example [Custom ListView Search](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/). If you can't get it then let me know I'll help you.